# List branches of particular remote in git

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04, git-branch

I have added multiple remote in one project.
How can check specific branch and push code on that remote with branch.

For Example.

```
origin  https://example1@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://example1@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git (push)
stash   http://example2@stash.xyz.com/scm/omed/repo.git (fetch)
stash   http://example2@stash.xyz.com/scm/omed/repo.git (push)
```

Here two remote added.
currently i got only origin branch not stash branch.

I want to list all the branches for particular remote.

When I do  the `git branch -a` I only see branches from origin

I need command for listing down stash remote branches.

Comment: `git pull stash <branch-name>` and `git push stash <branch-name>`. stash is bad name for remote though....

Comment: @Vishwanath , How can i check the branch of stash?

Comment: `git checkout -b <branch-name> stash/<branch-name>`

Comment: @Vishwanath, using git checkout -b <branch-name> stash/<branch-name>
it's created a new branch. not issue solve.

Comment: Did that solve your problem, Should I add that as an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74620/discussion-between-kkb-and-vishwanath).

Comment: `git fetch --all` followed by `git branch -a`

Comment: @hjpotter92, i got solution and i post answer. Thanks.

Comment: `git branch` shows you locally checked out branches, not only those from origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Steps follow.

1) Fetch the remote information. stash in this case is the remote name.

```
git fetch stash
```

2) Display remote branches

```
git branch -a
```

3) Now you can create local branch which is tracked by remote branch like following.

```
git checkout -b <branche-name>  stash/<branch-name>
```

4) Pull or push using the remote name

```
git pull stash <branch-name>
git push stash <branch-name>
```

Comment: This doesn't select a specific remote for the branch list, yet the question asks about a 'particular' remote, so I don't think this answers the original question. When one has say 7 remotes, with two from the upstream maintainers, the `branch -a` list becomes very long (1624 lines in my case). So, just sayin', the answer could be better;-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ævar's response to me asking on the Git list: https://public-inbox.org/git/87lfz3vcbt.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/

---

> Is there a command or simple simple invocation of branch, show-ref,
>   for-each-ref, etc that can be give a branch pattern and remote name to
>   quickly filter down the list of potential branches to just one or two
>   24-line screens?

That's:

```
git branch -a -l '<remote>/<pattern>'
git for-each-ref 'refs/remotes/<remote>/<pattern>'
```

The latter will conflate  with any local branches you happen to
have prefixed with .

The reason this isn't some easy mode in some command is because there's
no hard notion that a given remote "owns" a given set of RTB's. It's
just convention, but they can and do overlap sometimes.

---

Remember to use the appropriate * elements into the patterns. It's not a sub-string search.